# Install Paredit vim plugin on Mac OSX

Tags: vim, clojure, paredit

I recently download the [paredit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3998) plugin for vim on my mac osx.  I placed the paredit.vim in my ~/.vim directory.

The docs says:

```
When you enter a '(' then a matching ')' is automatically inserted.
If needed, spaces before and/or after the '()' pair are added.
...
Paredit mode is set by default for .lisp, .cl, .clj, cljs, .scm and .rkt files,
but it is possible to switch it off by putting the following statement in the
.vimrc file:
```

However when I open vim and enter a "(" no closing ")" is inserted.  Is there something else extra I need to do?

Comment: I did get it to start inserting closing "(" after placing this line in my .vimrc `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.clj call PareditInitBuffer()` but still not closing [ or {

Answer (score 1):

This did it for .clj files

```
syntax on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.clj setfiletype clojure
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.clj call PareditInitBuffer()
```